# What functions can I use to render a SkyPlane(explaiend below) in DirectX9?

Tags: directx, textures

Basically it's like a SkyBox,but a plane that is perfectly flat and infront of the screen.My idea is to have a big texture and depending on how you rotate the camera it renders different parts of the texture on the plane as if you are moving relative to the "sky" drawn on the plane and when you reach the edge it renders it +the part from the other side(I'll use a seamless texture,so it won't look seamed).I have figured out the formulas to do it,but I'm not sure what method to use.I mean I'm not sure if I should do it in C++ or is it supposed to be done in the shader in some .fx file and directly on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is draw a full-screen quad behind the rest of your scene, or use depth states to push it out to infinity.

If you want a simple plane, then you create the four necessary verts, bind your texture, and draw (disable writing to depth), then go about drawing the rest of the scene. This is done with a simple draw call in your C++, although you can use vertex buffers and such if necessary.

If you need something more complex, like layers or parallax, you'll need to use multiple planes and shift them, or a shader to composite multiple textures.

Comment: yeah,but I can't seem to find a function that takes source coordinates to make a texture out of a part of a bigger texture.

Comment: You don't need to, you just set the vertexes' texture coordinates to a region within the whole texture and the hardware will properly handle sampling. If you have an extremely large texture, you can use `IDirect3DDevice9::StretchRect`, `IDirect3DDevice9::UpdateTexture`, `IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect`, or some combination, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @peachykeen How to do it by changing the background color from white to skyblue without any texture.what should be the RGB start and end limits and which component R,G,B should be varied ?